# Unable to link org-mode capture items to mu4e email messages

Tags: org-mode, mu4e

I have been using `org-mode` for a while and started using `mu` and `mu4e` recently.

The following capture template stores a link from a "normal" file but not from a mu4e message:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
  '(("f" "Todo (linked to file)" entry (file+headline "~/org/gtd.org" "project")
 "* TODO %?\n%a"))
  )
```

In a buffer with a `mu4e` message, I do `M-x org-store-link` and get this message in the minibuffer:

> No method for storing a link from this buffer`.

The author of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254967/using-org-capture-templates-with-mu4e) reported that

> The link (%a) gets initialized,

and the [only other thread I found](https://mu-discuss.narkive.com/N4x66ce5/problems-with-mu4e-and-capture) is two years old and mentions that the problem went away with version `0.9.18` of `mu`.

I am running Org mode version **9.1.9** and `mu` version **1.0.**

How can I get the link to work?

Comment: not sure about the template but `M-x org-store-link` from the body of the email message does store a link that can be copied into org with 'M-x org-insert-link` and opened with `follow-link` or `C-c C-o`. I'll look further.

Comment: and this is for a hyperlink and not for a capture ..by the way.

Comment: I guess you need `(require 'org-mu4e)` somewhere in your init

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example that works for me and that I have somewhere from the mu4e-pages

```
(require 'org-mu4e)

(setq org-capture-templates
   '(("T" "todo with link" entry (file "~/org/inbox.org")
      "* TODO %i%? \n:PROPERTIES: \n:CREATED: %U \n:END: \n %a\n")
     ("p" "Process" entry (file+headline "~/org/gtd.org" "Tasks")
      "* TODO [#A] Process mail from %:fromname on %:subject\nSCHEDULED:%t\nDEADLINE: %(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t \"+2d\"))\n:PROPERTIES:\n:CREATED: %U\n:END:\n %a" :immediate-finish t :prepend t)))
```

For an explanation see https://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-hyperlink-types.html
and note that in `org-mu4e` among other things different kinds of hyperlink types for mu4e are defined.

Comment: `(require 'org-mu4e)` is all I needed to make the capture template work. Thanks!

Comment: I am very interested in this portion of this template  `%(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t \"+2d\"))` Is there any way to offset the deadline by two days but relative to the date when the email was received (rather than the current date/time)? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use one org-read to read the date from your mail an another to increment the day %(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t \"++2d\" nil (org-read-date nil t \"%:date\")))

Comment: @andrej Thanks, and thank you for answering my own related question :-)