# mu4e-org link storing - "No method for storing a link from this buffer" error

Tags: org-mode, mu4e

### The problem

I've recently moved to using mu4e for viewing and organising my email. I'm trying to use the function `org-store-link` in a mu4e message buffer but I encounter the error:

> No method for storing a link from this buffer

### Research/tests

I looked up the problem and found someone with a similar issue:
[Unable to link org-mode capture items to mu4e email messages](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46468/unable-to-link-org-mode-capture-items-to-mu4e-email-messages)

However, the solution in this case was to add `(require 'org-mu4e)` to the init.el file. I'm running mu4e version 1.5.7, and AFAIK, they have moved the link storing functions to mu4e-org.el (see https://github.com/djcb/mu/tree/master/mu4e), which is loaded by default when `mu4e-org-support` has value `t` (I have checked using `M-x describe-variable` and this is the case). Even if I do write `(require 'mu4e-org)` or `(require 'org-mu4e)` in my init.el file, I get the same error.

I looked at the source code for org (https://github.com/bzg/org-mode/blob/master/lisp/ol.el, I'm using version 9.3) and used `M-x describe-symbol` to print the value of `org-link-parameters`, and I can see the entry for mu4e which is:

```
 ("mu4e" :follow mu4e-org-open :store mu4e-org-store-link)
```

I also ran the code:

```
(cl-loop for link in org-link-parameters
       with store-func
       do (setq store-func (org-link-get-parameter (car link) :store))
       if store-func
       collect store-func)
```

in my scratch buffer, which is from the function `org-store-link-function` in ol.el, and this returns `(... mu4e-org-store-link)` which looks good.

So I think the problem might lie in the fact `org-store-link` calls this function and returns a `nil` value. But I've checked the mu4e-org source code and I think this should run correctly so long as I'm in the mu4e-header or mu4e-message major mode.

Does anyone have any idea where the problem is or any additional tests I should run?